# iPad Animation of modal view controller from table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, modalviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

So I'm creating an iPad app that displays images in a UITableView and when when a row/image is selected it pushes another view controller that plays a video in full screen. This is all working correctly but I want to animate the transition from the image's original size in the table to the fullscreen video. This video here displays what I want at about 1 second in http://www.apple.com/ipad/videos/#itunes. So how would I get the frame of the cell that is selected? And how would I transition the view from the cell frame to full screen?

Here is how I am doing the transition now:

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) 
    {
        VideoViewController * video1 = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:video1];
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

        [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open source project called [UAModalPanel](https://github.com/coneybeare/UAModalPanel) which does something very smiler to what you are trying to achieve. You would need to get your cell view by calling the UITableView method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Then you need to convert the cell's center point to the superview coordinate plane by using:

```
 - (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view;
```

Then you can pass this center point to the panel to show from there.

*full disclosure*: I am the maintainer of the project.